# Can child scope $apply itself without applying parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible for a child `$scope` (isolated or not) to do `$scope.$apply` without the parrent scope being applied?

There is some expensive computation going on (that is hard to cache) in the parent scope and I don't need angular to rerun the computation again.

for instance:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController"> 
{{ expensiveFunction() }}
  <div directive>
    <h1 ng-click="applyChildScopeOnly()">Click {{ value }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div directive>
    <h1 ng-click="applyChildScopeOnly()">Click {{ value }}</h1>
  </div>
<button ng-click="applyChildrenScope()"/> <!-- apply to children scope only -->
</div>
```

The directive:

```
module.directive('directive', ['$document','$rootScope', function ($document,$rootScope) {

  return{
    restrict:'AE',
    scope:{},
    link:function($scope, element, attrs){
        $scope.applyChildScopeOnly = function(){
           $scope.$apply(); // don't apply changes to $parent scope
        };

    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `$scope.$digest()` instead of `$scope.$apply()` to re-evaluate watches in the current scope and all its children. Calling `$scope.$digest()` wont't evaluate any watches on any parent scopes.

As a side note, the `$scope.$apply()` calls the `$rootScope.$digest()` behind the scenes.

More info here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope